# swift protocol extension with kvo

Tags: swift, protocols, avplayer, key-value-observing

I want to create a protocol that has default kvo functionality. However I am having issues having a protocol extension inherit NSObject. When I try to override `observeValue(forKeyPath` I get an error `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. Here is some sample code of what I am trying to do

```
protocol VideoTest {
  var player:AVPlayer { get set }
  func trackVideoStart()
}


struct ObserverContexts {
   static var playerRate = 0
}

extension VideoTest where Self: NSObject {

   func addPlayerObservers() {
       player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.rate),
                       options: ([.old, .new]),
                       context: &ObserverContexts.playerRate)
   }

    //gives error
    override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?,
                                  context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

     }

}
```

Is it possible to be able to use KVO via a protocol extension since I can't directly inherit from NSObject?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift but how about `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)`? See Key-Value Observing in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler looks for the function you are overriding on the VideoTest protocol itself.  The where clause is just telling it to only do the extension when the VideoTest is of the NSObject type.

Regardless of whether this did work or not you can't actually do this anyway because extensions cannot override functions at all.  See the swift documentation for extensions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) particularly this bit:

> NOTE
>
> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot
>   override existing functionality.